# how to make horizontal navigation to the right in css?

Tags: css

How can I make a page navigation similar to [my drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su5Hz.png)? I have been experimenting with stuff but cant get it right, I haven't been doing this very long. Thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/su5Hz.png]
Basically I have a header with an h1 title vertically centered and to the left then I want to add a nav to the bottom of the header in buttons at the right side. Both left and right having a little padding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! I suggest you take a look at [ask] as well as writing a [mcve]. If you expect to get answers, you need to post your code, what you have tried, and a complete description of the problem. If you don't your question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#aa13d6fa8428d30f78a9685caf745cf5

As [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093792/710887) said [display flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) would most likely be what you're looking for here. However my snippet below is an alternative to `display: flex`. (I omitted vendor prefixes and am using [Prefix-free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) for cross browser support).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 16px arial;
}

.heading {
  background: rgb(235,241,246);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(235,241,246) 0%, rgb(171,211,238) 50%, rgb(137,195,235) 51%, rgb(213,235,251) 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.24em #3c34e0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8.32%;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 2.84em;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
      <h1 class="header">Website title!</h1>
      
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#">Lorem.</a>
        <a href="#">Vitae.</a>
        <a href="#">Nihil!</a>
        <a href="#">Error.</a>
        <a href="#">Minus.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css on your nav container, it should do what you are after:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/f0xM1Fs here is the picture of what im trying to do, doing that for whatever reason made the nav go below the h1

Comment: On your picture the nav *IS* below the h1 (and aligned right). That's what I interpreted what "to the bottom of the header in buttons at the right side" should mean. You need to post some code, a clearer description and possibly a codepen or JSfiddle to get more specific answers...